# ON_EN_KILLFOCUS and [Enter] event is not getting raised for CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am stuck while working on CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton control.Please find the details :

I have an CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton control in my toolbar. I am using ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI to update any changes in UI. Hence for each entry the ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI handler is being called. I am typing 0.1234 so for the first entry i.e 0, i am validating the data in the handler. Since the value is 0 which is invalid number, i am modifying to some default value. Hence i am not able to type any value less than 0 since it is always modifying it to default value.

My requirement is to validate the entered values only after typing all the values.
I tried ON_EN_KILLFOCUS. Here i am not able to get the handler called. Also it will not work if i press [Enter] after typing the value. It is suppose to validate the data on pressing [Enter] as well.

Please find the code snippet for ON_EN_KILLFOCUS

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(FormDocument, BaseDocument)
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(ID_EDITCTRL, OnKillFocus)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void FormDocument::OnKillFocus()
 {
    // my stuff
    // How to get the control here ????
  }
```

Please suggest how can i get [Enter] and kill focus event

Thanks

Comment: Pressing the Enter button does not trigger a WM_KILLFOCUS event. Implement your validation also in your "OnEnterPressed" handler. BTW validating "on the" fly as in the previous requirement is far better IMO.

Comment: I can understand validating on the fly is better but there is a problem with this in my scenario explained below :                                                                        
For example : i want to enter something like 0.525. In such case when i am typing 0 then it is getting validated, since 0 is not allowed it is resetting it to previous value.

Comment: If you wish to do field validation on focus loss, handle [EN_KILLFOCUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761682.aspx). However, [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040419-00/?p=39753). Plus, pressing [Enter] does not cause an edit control in a toolbar to lose focus. Either you misunderstood your requirement, or you tested a sequence of input events that doesn't resemble your requirement.

Comment: I understood pressing [Enter] doesn't cause to lose focus. As per my requirement i have to validate the data when control will lose focus or one presses the Enter.

Comment: @NihalKumar so you need to do the validation in the `ON_EN_KILLFOCUS` handler __and__ in your "OnEnterPressed" handler.

Comment: Actually i am using CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton. I am not able to defined these events. Also this is define in a class which is inherited from cdocument class so i am facing problem in defining OnKeyDown handler.

Comment: Changing the question through information provided in additional comments isn't going to help anyone. Please provide a clear problem statement, together with a [mcve].

Comment: ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI is useful for updating the UI status (basically enabling/disabling menu items and toolbar buttons), based on user actions or data changes. A very convenient and powerful mechanism, as you don't need to remember putting some UpdateUI() call in every point that could modify the UI status, instead you update the item in a single point, based on conditions. Only prob, it's called all the time, even on mouse move events - don't put any slow or lengthy operations in there. Capturing user input in such an event is at least very unusual.

Comment: Please read [TN021: Command and Message Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt2c310k.aspx). Also keep in mind: MFC is for **experienced** Windows developers. If you don't know how to write this application without using MFC, there is no chance whatsoever that you succeed writing this application with the help of MFC.